# Questions can be made Community-Wiki by adding the right parameter when editing

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-wiki, security, privileges

See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/67604/revisions for a proof-of-concept.

It seems that, the community-wiki checkbox is only hidden for general users, but it is not validated on server-side. This makes it possible for the client side to inject the CW checkbox and force a question to be CW even if the user isn't a mod.

Comment: @Kenny, security through obscurity only works if you leave things obscured.

Comment: Nice! So the Community Wiki Police is now the Community Wiki *Secret* Police. Not bound by silly trials and human rights, we fight to prevent *all* illegitimate rep gain. Bwahahahahaha!

Comment: @radp: Not "still". The question I've linked was not composed by me, so in principle I should not be able to turn it to CW even before today's change.

Comment: @Kenny: oh wow.

Comment: Here's a question: Why is *this* question Community Wiki when it doesn't appear anywhere in the revision history?

Comment: Additionally: Although this is probably serious, it's less serious than it sounds; using this exploit will only make the *question* Community Wiki, not the *answers* which is what happens when a moderator does it.  So as a regular user concerned about rep-farming, there'd be no real benefit to doing this as opposed to flagging for moderator attention.

Comment: @Aarobot: (1) I checked the CW checkbox when posting the question. (2) Right, but I fear that the answers can also be force-CW'ed one by one. I haven't checked if it's possible.

Comment: @Kenny: Yeah, I thought of that a few minutes after posting my comment.  Still, that would be damn tedious.

Comment: @Aarobot Nothing greasemonkey couldn't fix.

Comment: But can you *uncheck* CW through parameters?

Comment: Does anyone know if moderators can reverse CW back to owned by user?

Comment: @Null: AFAIK, mods cannot reverse CW.

Comment: @Null Definitive version of Kenny's comment: Community Wiki cannot be reversed by mods.

Comment: @KennyTM ... I unwikid this, but moderators do not have access to this kind of feature as it would possibly result in data loss (eg. for a CW->normal->CW chain)

Comment: @Null I guess @waffles has given us the answer - yes, but only those with superpowers can unwiki

Comment: @waffles: Is that a developer-level feature, or did you have to hack at the DB? Just curious.

Comment: @Jon, I hacked the db, I could add the feature for devs, but not sure its worth it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well this was a bug, turns out security by obscurity has its own pitfalls.

Will be deployed to the rest of the sites later.